# A Utility to Spoof MAC addresses in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, networking, mac-address, spoofing

Is there a menu bar style tool, or maybe a GUI program that would allow me to switch / spoof MAC addresses for the Airport / WiFi connection on OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really can pass up the GUI interface for this one - it's a one-liner:

> `sudo ifconfig en1 lladdr aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff`

If you absolutely want it to be easy, use an apple script so you can click it in your menu bar. [This discussion](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-23024.html) can help with syntax.

> `tell application "Terminal"`
>   `do script "/path/to/script"`
>   `end tell`

The best reference is [**here**](http://osxdaily.com/2008/01/17/how-to-spoof-your-mac-address-in-mac-os-x/), though there are handy too:

http://josteinb.com/2009/10/spoofing-your-mac-address-in-snow-leopard/
http://www.macgeekery.com/gspot/2006-04/mac_address_spoofing
http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=7673

Comment: I would actually make two apple scripts - one to spoof and one to revert back. This information should set you up to do so.

Answer (score 1):

- [LinkLiar](https://github.com/halo/LinkLiar), free
- [WiFiSpoof](https://wifispoof.com), paid (was free)

Both menu bar utilities, 10.10+ (LinkLiar had a prefpane ≤10.9, WiFiSpoof used to work also ≤10.9).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know I can do it from the terminal or via applescript, but I was hoping for a menu bar utility.

And for the record, I actually find that I have to do this to spoof the mac-address on OS X 10.7:

```
//disassociate from airport - sometimes you need to run it twice
airport -z
airport -z

//find the current mac address
ifconfig en1 | grep ether

//i find I usually need to run this command at least twice before it works
sudo ifconfig en1 ether 00:e2:e3:e4:e5:e6
sudo ifconfig en1 ether 00:e2:e3:e4:e5:e6
sudo ifconfig en1 ether 00:e2:e3:e4:e5:e6

//check the mac again to see if it has changed
ifconfig en1 | grep ether
```

To get the `airport` terminal command you may need to add this:

```
alias airport="/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport"
```

Answer (score 0):

MacSpoofer can be downloaded from [www.macspoofer.com](http://www.macspoofer.com).

It is a free utility to change your Mac address on OS X. It installs itself in the 'System Preferences' where it has a GUI to change and also generate a new MAC address for all your network devices.

Answer (score 0):

This script changes MAC address every 290 seconds - works on mavericks: 
 1. Create new file called autoChangeMac.sh -> paste the code below
 2. Run it with `sudo sh autoChangeMac.sh`
 3. Profit

```
#!/bin/bash

while :        # while true
do 

openssl rand -hex 1 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' | xargs echo "obase=2;ibase=16;" | bc | cut -c1-6 | sed 's/$/00/' | xargs echo "obase=16;ibase=2;" | bc | sed "s/$/:$(openssl rand -hex 5 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')/" | xargs sudo ifconfig en0 ether

echo "Change! $(date -u) "
sleep 290
done
```